# Hello.js Successful Login but Cannot get data

Tags: api, contacts, live, hello.js

I am trying to get contacts from google account and windows live using Hello.js, I did copy paste hello.js examples. The popup login is done successfully with no problem in OAuth, but I can't get any data back.
I explored a lot about this and realized that auth.login is not triggered:

```
hello.on('auth.login', function(auth){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'LogIn Success';
});
```

I tried several demos from Hello.js page but nothing worked for me:
https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/tree/master/demos

Here is the setup that I used:

```
<script>
hello.init({ 
    facebook : FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
    windows  : WINDOWS_CLIENT_ID,
    google   : GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
},{redirect_uri:'https://www.example/back.php'});
</script>
```

Redirect url is just an empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I have to include hello.js in the redirect page (back.php):

```
<script src="hello.js"></script>
```